# Sql server mouse cursor pointer does NOT automatically go to the end of the line

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, usability

This is a plain usability issue I'm facing. Somehow the settings on my version changed and when I click on the query window, the mouse cursor pointer does NOT  automatically go to the end of the line. It instead remains wherever I had clicked.

I have checked Options in Tools, but I cannot find where this feature can be reset.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got the [virtual space](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/02/28/understanding-virtual-space-vstipedit0023.aspx) option enabled in your settings.

On the menu bar, go to the *Tools* -> *Options*, and then pick *Text Editor* -> *All Languages* and uncheck the `Enable virtual space` option.

Take a look at this screenshot:

[image: Virtual Space]